# How to segue to a specific view controller inside a tab bar controller with losing the tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Currently I have a tab bar controller that is connected to various navigation controllers like this:

[image: storyboard]

I'm trying to navigate from one view controller to another view controller that is in a separate navigation controller.  The only way I've been able to figure out how to keep the tab bar from disappearing is to create a modal segue to the original tab bar controller.  The only problem doing this it automatically goes to the default tab bar viewcontroller and not the one I'm trying to reach.

Comment: You need to send call a method on your existing tab bar controller subclass instance.  This method needs to select a specific tab and then select the required view controller in the relevant navigation controller

Comment: This is the first time I've used a tab bar controller, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: First, you will need to create a sublcass of UITabBar and use that, just like you subclass UIViewController.  This lets you add a function to select a specific tab/view controller.  Then you need to make sure which ever view controller wants to change the current view has a reference to the tab bar controller instance; either from a property or just looking at the view controller hierarchy

Comment: i've seen stuff like: tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1, but how to determine which viewcontroller is at what selectedIndex?

Comment: You should know that; It is your app, index 0 is the left most, the next is 1 and so on